# New stream from a streaming topic (Json format) without any data

Tags: ksqldb

I have a streaming topic in Json with 50 fields. I try to create another stream with 1 field using KSQL from the topic as below:

```
create stream data (timeGMT string) with (kafka_topic='json_data', value_format='json');
```

The stream was created successfully, however no data returns from below KSQL query:

```
select * from data;
```

This is running on KSQL  5.0.0

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to check, including:

- Is there any data in the topic?

  ```
  PRINT 'json_data' FROM BEGINNING;
  ```
- Have you told KSQL to read from the beginning of the topic?

  ```
  SET 'auto.offset.reset' = 'earliest';
  ```
- Are there messages in your topic that aren't JSON or can't be parsed? Check the KSQL Server log for errors.

You can see more information on these, and other troubleshooting tips, [in this blog](https://www.confluent.io/blog/troubleshooting-ksql-part-1).